# Network trials and tribulations

Tags: windows-7, home-networking

I am in the process of setting up a small (two PC's, both running Windows 7) network using a D-link DI-604 router (which acts only as hub, it's not set up in any way).

In the Network and 'Sharing Center' in 'Control Panel' I clicked 'Set up a New (Connection or) Network'.

All went well up until the moment I attempted to connect one PC with the other (in the 'Connect' dialog I entered the other PC's IP, no pwd).  I can use both PC's to connect to and browse the net though, so the router/hub does not seem to be the problem.

And I must have done something right, because the other computer shows up in the 'Network Map'.

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: What type of connection are you trying to establish?  Shared folders? Remote desktop connection? If you can tell us more about your goals, it will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hello Joe, I want to be able to get at one computers files and resources (e.g. printer) from the other,
One of the PC's has two network adapters - perhaps I'd be better off (less headache) using a patch-cable (red, FTP) between the two?
Please bear with me as this is important to me :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to have a completely separate network between the two PCs.  You can have one network that connects to the outside world and your other PC.  Using a [Windows 7 Homegroup](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-in-windows-7-with-homegroup/) is going to be the easiest way to set this up.